# how to filter list in angular 2 using pipe?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am trying to filter my list using **pipe** I didn't get expect out .I don't knwo how to send `input` field value to pipe.

here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/WFMo8Az7BSJaRJAVVxyE?p=preview
when I type "a" it should only display "abc" in list

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({ name: 'listpipe' })
export class ListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], filter: string) {
     if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
  return items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf(filter) !== -1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass the values string (the value of the input text) to your filter.

So in the component class, it should be :

```
<li *ngFor="let l of v  | listpipe:values">{{l.name}}</li>
```

Instead of :

```
<li *ngFor="let l of v  | listpipe">{{l.name}}</li>
```

You can find more information of the pipes parameters in the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#parameterizing-a-pipe